How to convert residual predictions back to original unit in a multiple regression model
I am trying to use a multiple-linear regression model based on observed air temperature (ta) and precipitation (pr) time series to project future soil temperatures (ts). My goal is to assess how much warmer/cooler soil temps will be in 2025-2034 compared to a 2010-2019 benchmark.
I started by constructing the model using 2000-2009 ta and pr data (R code below). I detrended and scaled the predictors and predictand and build the model based on the predictor's residual to make the model more statistically robust.
library(pracma)

#Data (fake)
yr <-  c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019) #year
ts <-  c(33,36,38,37,39,41,40,40,41,43) #soil temps (Celsius
ta <-  c(20,22,24,23,25,28,26,25,27,29) #air temps (Celsius)
pr <-  c(6,5,4,3,4,2,3,2,2,1) #precip (mm/day)

#Detrend and scale predictors and predictand
tsx <-  as.numeric(scale(detrend(ts)))  #soil temp 
tax <-  as.numeric(scale(detrend(ta)))  #air temp
prx <-  as.numeric(scale(detrend(pr)))  #precip

#Find multi-linear regression model
df <-  data.frame(yr = yr, ts=tsx, ta=tax, pr=prx)
model <- lm(ts~ta+pr+I(pr^2)+ta:pr, data=df) 
print(summary(model)) #the real model has a better fit

#Use model to predict 2010-2019 soil temps
tsx.prd <- predict(model,data=df)

#Compare observed and predicted soil temps
plot(tsx~yr,type="l", main="Sfc temps")
lines(tsx.prd~yr, type="l", col="red")
legend("topright", c("Obs","Model"), col=c("black","red"), lty=c(1,1))

Now I want to use this same model to project future soil temperature based on modelled air temperature and precipitation time series for 2025-2034. I started by detrending and scaling the 2025-2034 predictors (see below).
#New data (2010-2019 ta and pr)
yr.new <-  c(2025,2026,2027,2028,2029,2030,2031,2032,2033,2034) #year
ta.new <-  c(22,24,25,26,27,29,30,31,32,33) #air temps (Celsius)
pr.new <-  c(3,4,3,4,2,1,2,2,1,0.1)   #precip (mm/day)

#Detrend and scale predictors
tax.new <-  as.numeric(scale(detrend(ta.new)))  
prx.new <-  as.numeric(scale(detrend(pr.new))) 

#New data frame
df.new <-  data.frame(yr = yr.new, ta=tax.new, pr=prx.new)

#Get 2010-2019 soil temp projections
tsx.new.prd <- predict(model, newdata=df.new)

#Plot results
plot(tsx.new.prd~yr.new, type="l",col="blue",main="Ts projection")
legend("topright", c("Ts"), col=c("blue"), lty=c(1))

Question: How I do convert the 2025-2034 ts predictions (tsx.new.prd) back to their original units (non residual) so I can directly compare predictions against ts?
